# Running a Java program from the command line that depends on a jar file?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, classpath, javac

I have a simple Java file Q.java that depends on an external library file X.jar. Both Q.java and X.jar are in the same directory. I can compile Q.java from the command line by doing: "javac -cp X.jar Q.java". This generates a Q.class file. How do I run this now? I tried all these:

1) java Q
2) java -cp X.jar Q

I keep getting a 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Q
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Q

So how do I run this from the command line now that I have the class file?

Comment: Is there a `package` declaration in Q.java?

Comment: @TedHopp Would that make a difference? I have a similiar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156180/classpath-option-works-for-javac-but-not-for-java-windows

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
java -cp X.jar:. Q
```

You have to specify in the classpath that you want to use the JAR dependency AND the current local directory to resolve classes.

---

Edit suggested in the comments:

On Windows, replace `:` by `;`:

```
java -cp X.jar;. Q
```

Comment: In Windows, you have to use ";", not ":", so there it would be "java -cp X.jar;. Q"

Answer (score 0):

Set the current directory in your classpath, it should solve the problem. Most of the time, we need current directory in the classpath, so generally I advice to set "." (without quotes) in your system CLASSPATH environment variable instead of setting for each run.